# What is new in Visual Studio 2008 vs 2005 or C# 3.0 vs C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, .net-3.0

I was browsing the [Hidden Features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) question and thought I would try out one of the features I was unfamiliar with.  Unfortunately I use Visual Studio 2005 and the feature in question was introduced later.   Is there a good list for new features in C# 3.0 (Visual Studio 2008) vs. C# 2.0 (Visual Studio 2005)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a comprehensive list but these are some of my favorite new features of C# 3.0:

New type initializers. Instead of saying this:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "John Smith";
```

I can say this:

```
Person person = new Person() { Name = "John Smith" };
```

Similarly, instead of adding items individually, I can initialize types that implement IEnumerable like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };
```

The new syntax for lambda expressions is also nice. Instead of typing this:

```
people.Where(delegate(person) { return person.Age >= 21;);
```

I can type this:

```
people.Where(person => person.Age >= 21 );
```

You can also write extension methods to built in types:

```
public static class StringUtilities
{
    public static string Pluralize(this word)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Which allows something like this:

```
string word = "person";
word.Pluralize(); // Returns "people"
```

And finally. Anonymous types. So you can create anonymous classes on the fly, like this:

```
var book = new { Title: "...", Cost: "..." };
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple features I like:

- VS 2008 supports targeting various version of the .NET framework so you can target 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5
- Automatic properties are nice.

For example:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

instead of:

```
private int _id;
public int Id {
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
}
```

Comment: Arguably, you can get automatic properties by using code snippets in VS 2005 also.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-targetting support. You can build .NET 2 -> .NET 3.5 all from the one IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the MS page on .NET 3.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822048.aspx
...and on VS 2008 for C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383815.aspx

I haven't tried VS2008 and .NET 3.0 out, but I figure the links might help ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the unknown but powerful feature of Visual Studio 2008 is [T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). T4 is a code generator built right into Visual Studio 2008.

Check the [Scott Guthrie's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) blog post [Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5 Released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/19/visual-studio-2008-and-net-3-5-released.aspx). This post was written when Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5 is Released. This post has included lot of links for the new features of Visual Studio 2008 and C# 3.0.